How does Windows 10 eat up the space on system partition?
The free space on my system partition becomes less and less then Storage Sense is triggered. It seems whatever space you leave for the system partition, Windows 10 will eventually eat up that space. The disk clean tools can only free a little amount of space so are almost useless. I wonder how Windows 10 uses up the space on the system volume. I never installed apps to the system partition manually so it must be Windows 10 that used up the space. What folders/files besides the temp/Internet temporary file can I delete safely?

“Windows 10 will eventually eat up that space”—it really does not. But instead of speculating, I recommend you use a disk space analyzer like TreeSize Free, WizTree or WinDirStat. That way, you’ll be able to find what’s occupying all the space.

@DanielB So, do you mean if there is only several GB free space on the system partition, Windows 10 will stop eating up that space?

He's saying "run a tool that'll check and show you what's actually using that space" - I have treesize free and windir stat installed and they both give you  a lower level view and visualsation of what's using the space

you might have to run these as admin to get a full accounting. Also, the WinSxS tends to: 1) expand as time goes on and; 2) cause windows explorer to over-report used space since many of the WinSxS files are symbolic links to a single set of files and explorer double and triple counts the space. Do not touch or delete anything in this subfolder as it can break your install. see, for example ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11 )

and ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/installing-updates-features-roles/address-disk-space-issues-caused-by-winsxs )


How much space, total, is on that partition? 2. How much is Windows using? Show output from WinDirStat (https://windirstat.net/) or similar in the question.  3. What do you have enabled? Utilities such as Restore and File History use up space. 4. What cleanup have you done? Empty Trash Bin? Clean up WinSxs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11)? System cleanup (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/tips-to-free-up-drive-space-on-your-pc-4d97fc4a-0175-8d49-ac2f-bcf27de46d34)?


There are many questions on this site, and many guides elsewhere on the reputable internet regarding finding out what is using your disk space. You need to follow the information already available to find out WHAT is using your space, because the answer to THAT question is going to tell you your next steps to solve the root problem.
